# Rstudio keyring

Tags: r, ms-access, odbc

I can connect to a dsn with userid and password but I want to use something like keyring to use windows authentication/login password so that I don't need to use a plain text password. for example:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "oracledb", UID="tst", PWD= rstudioapi::askForPassword("Enter your Password"))
```

or

```
oraclecon=odbcConnect(dsn = "dsnname", uid = "tst", pwd = "*****", believeNRows=FALSE)
```

What I want is something like `con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "oracledb", UID="tst", PWD= "trusted_connection=true")`

I currently connect to DSNs in AccessDB but have to change my password every 3 months and I don't want to have to change them on every DB hence doing it in R.

Comment: Have you tried the `keyring` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dsn<-keyring::key_set(service = "oracledb", username = "tst")
con <- odbcConnect(dsn ="oracledb", 
                 uid = keyring::key_list(dsn$service,dsn$username)[1,2], 
                 pwd = key_get("oracledb", 
                               username = keyring::key_list(dsn$service,dsn$username)[1,2], 
                               keyring = NULL), believeNRows=FALSE) 

df=sqlQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM TRANS")
```